# Wireshark showing packet is received but the udp server does not get the packet

Tags: udp, protocols, ipv4

I have a `udp4 nodejs` server listening on `10.0.0.110:8808` and I am trying to send data from a embedded device to the node server. Wireshark is showing packet received

[image of wireshark received packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRo8O.png)

The header checksum for the `UDP` is set to `0`.
I can't figure out what is the reason.

Comment: Does the node server have a firewall? Wire shark shows the packet arrived at the interface, but a firewall could stop it getting  from there to the application.

Comment: The node server is a `local` server. So I it should not be behind a firewall right?

Comment: If you’re sending the packet to the 10.0.0.110 address (rather than 127.0.0.1) then it’s coming in just like external traffic and any firewall filtering that interface might apply.

Comment: `sudo ufw status` command is giving “Status: inactive”. That means firewall is disabled.                                

'sudo netstat -tulpn' command gives
`udp        0      0 10.0.0.110:8808         0.0.0.0:*                           22630/node  `

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. Actually, I wrote the ipv4 layer of the embedded device and had some problem with ipv4 header checksum calculation. Wire shark does not check the ipv4 header checksum by default. [found on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876145/java-udp-server-cant-receive-packet?rq=1) so no error was shown.

Now it's working fine.
Thanks for the comments  [**Shawn Wilson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4825744/shawn-wilson)